# Need Varnish configuration advice

Tags: varnish

I need some advice here for default.vcl. Here's the rules:

1. Only cache pages with urls that contains '/c/', the rest will pass
2. Set the cache expiry to 3 hours
3. Only cache and serve from cache if cookie 'abc' and cookie 'xyz' is empty

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.request ~ "^/c/") {
       if ( (req.http.cookie ~ "abc=;") && (req.http.cookie ~ "xyz=;") ){
        lookup;
       }
    }
    pass;
}
sub vcl_fetch {
    if (req.request ~ "^/c/") {
        set obj.ttl = 10800s;
    }
}
```

however, empty and not set are two different things.  Set up a test, you can use varnishlog on another session to see precisely what varnish is doing (it is quite detailed) and then adjust the rules to do what you need.